# MS Access Report_Page event doesn't execute when exporting to xps or pdf

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010

Using MS Access 2010, I have a simple table that contains basic information about rooms in an office building plus a path+filename for an image that I would like to display on form and/or report for that room.  Sometimes, but not always, the incorrect image will appear, typically when the room does not have an entry for an image.

I have corrected this the form by adding logic in the Form_Current event.  But I get random results when adding the same logic in the Report_Current and Report_Page events.

It seems that the Print Preview will correctly display the images, but exporting the print to XPS or PDF ignores the Report_Page and Report_Current code, which is the same as the Form_Current code below.

```
Private Sub Form_Current()

    Me.ImageHolder.Picture = ""
    If (Me.ImageFilePath.Value <> "") and Dir(Me.ImageFilePath.Value) <> "" Then 
        Me.ImageHolder.Picture = Me.ImageFilePath.Value
    Else
        Me.ImageHolder.Picture = ""

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the `Report_Page` or `Report_Current` are suitable events for your code. The Current event in particular is about Focus within the report, which is not applicable when printing (or saving). The Page event occurs too late, just before the page is actually printed.

Assuming each record's details, including the picture, are in the Details section of the report, then double-click the grey Detail-bar to bring up its properties. I suspect `OnFormat` is the event you need. There is `OnPrint` but I believe this might be too late. (There is `OnPaint` as well but, as I recall, this is quite specific and not often used on its own.)

Comment: Sorry, I tried the OnFormat, but still no luck.  Any suggestions would be helpful.  Thanks, JCL

Comment: I can't be certain which event, or section, would work, particularly as I don't have the report in front of me. For example, the Page-Header section also has similar events. Unless someone else contributes, do what I would do: experiment a little ;). I am assuming, as well, that `ImageFilePath`, etc., are all in the same section of the report.

Comment: Well, believe it or not, it seems that when I put the logic into the page header OnFormat event, it appears to work consistently correct.  So...Thanks :)